# Looping down a list of names and extracting data frame from a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, lapply, sapply, outer-apply

I have a list that stores 142 data frames
I have extracted the names of them into a vector

> d.names[1]
>   [1] "ACQ_C.XPT"

I used a function to create a true/false vector which contains a list of variables in each data frame that I wish to either keep or discard

> d1[1]
>   $ACQ_C.XPT
>      SEQN ACD010A ACD010B ACD010C  ACQ020  ACQ030  ACD040  ACQ050  ACQ060  ACD070  ACD080 
>      TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE

I wish to iteratively go down the list of the data frames and create data frames that include only those variables marked as true in vector d1

```
lapply(seq_along(d.names),function(i,x){as.data.frame(x[,rapply(d1[i], 
function(x) list(x))])x=d.names[i]})
```

> Error: unexpected symbol in "lapply(seq_along(d.names),function(i,x){as.data.frame(x[,rapply(d1[i], function(x) list(x))])x"

Comment: str(d[[1]])
'data.frame': 7344 obs. of  11 variables:                              str(d[[142]])
'data.frame': 6213 obs. of  42 variables:                 lapply(seq_along(d.names),function(i,x){as.data.frame(x[,rapply(d1[i], function(x) list(x))])},x=d)
Error in x[, rapply(d1[i], function(x) list(x))] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
Called from: as.data.frame(x[, rapply(d1[i], function(x) list(x))])

Comment: I managed to get an output by using lapply(seq_along(d.names),function(i,x){as.data.frame((d[[i]])[,rapply(d1[i], function(x) list(x))])},x=d)   now I need to iterate and add a dataframe name to each output ie d1[i] should be the name of each iteration